# Icons not showing up in Action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I am trying to get an action bar within my android app to show up with icons. No matter what I do, I only see the overflow icon with a dropdown, while I want to see the Home and Logout icons next to each other on the action bar menu. I have read through most posts on SO for a solution but am unable to find a solution. Can anyone please help ?

Below is my code :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".application.MySampleApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/letter"
    android:label="My Sample"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
```

**Menu_Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:title="@string/gohome"
        android:icon="@drawable/ulogo"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        logout();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_home) {
        goHome();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**How it shows up now**
[image: How it shows up now]

**How I want it to show up**

[image: Need to show]

Comment: What class does `MainActivity` extend? Why are you using `Theme.WithActionBar`?

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity. I thought using 'Theme.WithActionBar' was necessary to get the intended action bar. Was googling for a solution and saw someone use it and since that seemed to make sense, I added it. I am relatively new to Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Btw, it is the same behavior even when I tried using other themes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MainActivity extends Activity

This means that you are using the native action bar, not the backport offered by `appcompat-v7`. In that case, replace the `app:` prefixes in your menu resource with `android:`, and you will have better luck.

> Was googling for a solution and saw someone use it

That is surprising. Your question is the first time I have ever seen anyone use that theme. I didn't even know it existed until I looked it up as part of checking your question. Most likely, you will want to use more modern themes.

Comment: I tried replacing the prefix app: with android: but see an error in menu_main.xml. I used other themes as well but had no luck with them either.

Comment: @Prashanth: "but see an error in menu_main.xml" -- what is the error? And, are you sure that it is an error, and not a warning? For example, it may be complaining that you should be using `app:`. That would occur if you have `appcompat-v7` in your `dependencies`, as Android Studio then thinks that you should be using the action bar backport.

Comment: I think I got what you said. While I was reading up more on the app: vs android: prefixes, the error showed that I could use android: only if there was no appCompat in my build.gradle.  <br/> <code>
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jsonic-1.3.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
</code>

Comment: I am sorry, I was not able to format the code within my comments

Comment: @Prashanth: The real rule is that if you inherit from `AppCompatActivity`, you need to use the `app:` prefix in the menu resources and a theme based upon `Theme.AppCompat`. If you are not planning on using `AppCompatActivity`, delete the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` line from your `dependencies` closure.

Comment: I removed the line that said - ompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'. Will this cause any issues with my applications in terms of backward compatibility ?

Comment: @Prashanth: You will not have an action bar on API Level 10 and lower devices. Most likely, your `minSdkVersion` is significantly higher than 10.

Comment: I got it to work now. I removed the following lines <br/> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

Comment: My minDdkVersion is 17 within the build.gradle file. I never realized that android ties up so many of these things. So, if you can answer, I would appreciate how AppCompatActivity helps instead of extending from just Activity. When to use what ?

Comment: @Prashanth: Today, `appcompat-v7` is mostly used for a backport of the Material Design aesthetic. It allows apps running on Android 4.x to look like apps that run on Android 5.0+, in terms of the details of how the action bar, buttons, and so on all look. It also offers backports of a few other newer Android features, such as font resource support (introduced with Android 8.0). However, it significantly increases your APK size.

Comment: one last question - you mentioned that I had to use more modern themes. Can you suggest which theme might be useful in my case where I need to show an Action Bar ? Again, thank you for your help !

Comment: @Prashanth: The standard theme on Android 4.x devices is `Theme.Holo`. The standard theme on Android 5.0+ devices is `Theme.Material`. Both come with an action bar by default. Both will be dark, but there is `Theme.*.Light` and `Theme.*.Light.DarkActionBar` (where `*` is `Holo` or `Material`) for alternative base colors. You can create your own custom theme that inherits from these themes on the appropriate API levels. Your custom theme can also change some stock behavior (e.g., action bar color on `Theme.Material`). All of this should be covered in modern books on Android app development.